# Struts2 i18n messages

Tags: java, validation, properties, struts2, internationalization

I am using Struts 2 and I created a simple application following a tutorial I found.

I've created a `<MyActionClass>-validation.xml` file and I wonder how can I display the validation messages based on  multiple languages?

```
<field name="password">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <param name="trim">true</param>
        <message>You have to enter a password.</message> 
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Can I get the messages from a localized `.properties` file or do I have to use some other kind of validation?

Should there be validation XML files for every locale?

Comment: You should read Struts2 documentation http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/home.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `<message  key="key_name"/>` inside your `ActionClass-validation.xml`

Then you define `key_name` in

```
global.properties
global_vn.properties
```

Make sure you have `request_locale` in your stack.

Answer (score 3):

The messages are retrieved by `key` from you localized properties. You don't have to write duplicate code for validation. For example

```
<validators>
   <validator type="requiredstring">
     <param name="fieldname">field.name</param>
     <message key="field.key"/>
   </validator>
</validators>
```

or using annotations

```
private String name;

@RequiredStringValidator(key = "field.key")
public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
}
```

`field.name` is a resource key for a field label while `field.key` is a key to an error message.

in the properties you write

```
field.name=MyName 
field.key=MyName required
```

that is localized.

Messages automatically retrieved depending on the locale settings of the user browser or via `request_locale` parameter that is setting locale by the [I18N interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/i18n-interceptor.html) independent of the browser settings. So, make sure you have it on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getText` method to get message from properties file.

```
<message>${getText("enter.password")}</message>
```

See: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-LocalizingandParameterizingMessages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get localized messages from a properties file and no there is no need of any validation.xml for any locale specific messages.

You need to specify the ResourceBundle which will be nothing but different locales files of extension .properties